# React has detected a change in the order of Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to display some cards based on user data that i get from an API.
But this error keep showing:
`Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by PlanCard. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks

### Previous render            Next render

1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useState                   useState
4. useEffect                  useEffect
5. undefined                  useContext

   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   `

this is all my PlanCard file

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false),
    [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

  let headless = typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.location.search.includes('?headless'),
    platform =
      typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
        window.location.search.includes('platform=')
        ? new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('platform')
        : false,
    access_token =
      typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
        window.location.search.includes('access_token=')
        ? new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('access_token')
        : false,
    plans = [],
    payment_plan = null,
    plan_id = null,
    modal = null,
    purchased_from = null;

  if (headless && access_token) {
    payment_plan = useFetchData(access_token);
    plan_id = payment_plan.plan_id;
  } else { 
    // ToDo:
  }
  if (typeof plan_id === 'string') {
    plans = getPlanCards(plan_id, payment_plan.current_plan_status.toLowerCase());
    purchased_from = payment_plan.purchased_from;
    modal = getPlanCardsANAAlert(purchased_from);
  }
};
```

also this is my fetchPlan code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const useFetchData = (access_token) => {
  const [plan, setPlan] = useState({});
  let componentMounted = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.GATSBY_API_URL}user/plan/current_plan_detail?token=${access_token}`
        );
        if (componentMounted) {
          setPlan(response.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
    return () => {
      componentMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return plan;
};

export default useFetchData;
```

Comment: Please use a code block instead of each line.. That makes it very hard to understand

Comment: Just based on a a search of the page, I don't see `useEffect` or `useContext` used in the code you provided. Please post all relevant code - is `PlanCard` rendering children (possibly incorrectly)?

Comment: `useFetchData` looks like a custom hook. If so, you cannot call it inside a `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a hook in an if statement

```js
if (headless && access_token) {
  payment_plan = useFetchData(access_token);
  plan_id = payment_plan.plan_id;
}
```

This makes your hooks unstable between renders of the component, React uses hooks to determine the state of the component and keeps track of the hooks that a component has defined in an array, and if they are different between renders this means it cannot compare the state correctly. Have a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

To work around this you can use something like this:

```js
const payment_plan = useFetchData(access_token);
if(headless && payment_plan) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me, because I want payment_plan to get value only when headless and access_token have value on the url

Comment: I even tried to declare both payment_plan and plan_id outside the if statement and removed if statement, but the error is still popping up

Comment: in that case, fetching the data needs to have a reliance on an external factor to be called, for example, the call doesn't happen if the headless and payment_plan are null. You can do that by making it that there are params to you're useFetchData(), or make useFetchData return a callback that you can call to make the fetch happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently seen this bug which looked like the following:

---

Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by `DashboardSidebar`. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed.

| Previous render | Next render |
| --- | --- |
| `useContext` | `useContext` |
| `useContext` | `useContext` |
| `useContext` | `useContext` |
| `useDebugValue` | `useDebugValue` |
| `useState` | `useState` |
| `useEffect` | `useEffect` |
| `undefined` | `useContext` |

---

**Scenario:**

In the `DashboardSidebar` component, I had two children components for the side navigation bar which were conditionally replacing each other.
In only one of the components, I used the following code due to which I was getting this error:

```
const settingsContext = useCompanySettingProvider();

// INFO: here I was accessing the value from a useContext hook
```

**Explaination:**

1st child component: Included `settingsContext`.
2nd child component: **NOT** included `settingsContext`.

When I refreshed while the 2nd child component was rendered, the `settingsContext` along with the 1st child was removed. And when I tried to get into the scenario where 1st component (with `settingsContext`) was rendered, this error was thrown.

The main reason was that now the `useContext` was present in the next render but not in the previous one which is against the rules of hooks.

**Solution:**

I simply moved the `settingsContext` in the parent component where the `settingsContext` calling will not be changed in between the renders.

**Do let me know if you have any queries or feedback on this answer.**

Answer (score 0):

React documentation say:

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

You should use the same flow for your hooks, you can't have differents hooks during a re-rendering of a page